# Uncertainty in image with known camera specifications

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Given an image produced by a sensor-lens combination, is there a way to roughly estimate the error / uncertainty of the image pixels, if the characteristics of the sensor and the lens are known (field of view, resolution, f-number etc.)?

Comment: There is no such thing as "error / uncertainty of the image pixels"  what do you mean?

Comment: Maybe I am describing this in the wrong way, but basically I mean the uncertainty associated with a pixel value, due to noise etc. For example, because a real world camera is not an ideal pinhole camera, if I want to measure the position of an object in the real world using a camera (given prior knowledge of the camera pose in the world) I want to know the uncertainty / error introduced by the camera imperfections.

Comment: ok that makes more sense. your question is too broad and off-topic then. you cannot derrive optical aberrations and noise from simple camera specifications. they are just nominal values. you would have to test your system vs many different well known calibration targets.

Comment: But is there no component of the hardware specifications where some part of the error can be derived? For example, I could imagine that pixel size and resolution affects the minimal distance that can be measured.

Comment: of course you can derive some information from those specifications. if you understand digital imaging you can do that. but that's something you cannot learn here.

Comment: Are you aware of any good sources? Or some keywords I can look up? Because so far I haven't been able to find many papers or material directly connecting hardware specifications to the maths behind error estimation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220795/discussion-between-sguard-and-piglet).

Answer (score 1):

You can derive some fairly lose bounds from a camera's (lens, mount, sensor) nominal specifications, which may or may not be adequate for your application.

Estimating anything more precisely will likely yield results valid only for one specific camera configuration and environment setup, and the estimation process will likely require sophisticated lab equipment (optical bench, vibration damping, temperature control, calibrated strobes, calibrated observation targets).

If you are interested in learning about the optical side of these problems, you could start from [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0240515404).

Comment: Thanks, I want to find out the position of an object from an image, but it seems that only the pixel resolution can give me a bound so far.